# WooCommerce review-order.php sorting

Tags: woocommerce

We need to have two tables in review-order.php to display Invoiced items in Table 1 and Credit Card Purchases in Table 2.

Here I have a basic overview of the concept.

```
    <?php if($gateways == 'bacs') { ?>
      <div id="order_review">   
        <table class="shop_table">
         <thead>            
           <tr>
             <th class="product-name"><?php _e('Invoice Products', 'yit'); ?></th>
             <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e('Qty', 'yit'); ?></th>
             <th class="product-total"><?php _e('Totals', 'yit'); ?></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
```

TABLE 2

```
     <?php if($gateways == 'paypal') { ?>
       <div id="order_review">
        <table class="shop_table">
         <thead>            
           <tr>
             <th class="product-name"><?php _e('Credit Card Products', 'yit'); ?></th>
             <th class="product-quantity"><?php _e('Qty', 'yit'); ?></th>
             <th class="product-total"><?php _e('Totals', 'yit'); ?></th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
```

The problem is that the tables disappear completely when wrapped within an IF.

If anyone could help with at least some better ideas that would be much appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you getting the $gateways variable from?  Without knowing, it is hard to see why your code doesn't work.  But here is the code to get the gateways.

$available_gateways = $woocommerce->payment_gateways->get_available_payment_gateways();

```
foreach ( $available_gateways as $gateway ) {
     if ( $gateway->chosen === 'paypal' ) {
          // do something
     }

     // alternative you can try id if that matches
     if ( $gateway->id === 'paypal' ) {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your alternative way has served its purpose but now for some reason the filter I have setting the gateway for the products seems to be getting reset before review-order.php. Only the paypal is displaying products and its displaying both paypal and bacs products :(. I have code to show for it but need reputation.

Comment: Yea sorry I didnt want to post it in this comment area as the formatting is not near substantial. I am new to stackoverflow so bare with me as I build reputation up as needed.

Comment: Also I did figure out how to split the table by Invoice and PayPal by calling the actual product ID's in_array